# Pulling out realm element from realm data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I started Swift coding just a few days ago.... and I really need some help.

I made two different swift files by importing RealmSwift.
Calling each AAA, and BBB, the elements I have in the two can be named as below:

```
class AAA: Object {
  dynamic var name: String? nil
  let x = RealmOptional<Int>()
  let y = RealmOptional<Int>()
  let width = RealmOptional<Int>()
  let height = RealmOptional<Int>()
  }

class BBB: Object {
  dynamic var imageData: Data? = nil
  dynamic var title: String? = nil
  let myList = List<AAA>()
  }
```

so here I am trying to call up the information of the classes above, and part of the codes that I wrote is:

```
func callUp () {
  if let info = self.infoFromPrevController {
  let callSize: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int))
  view.addSubview(callSize)
  }
```

I'm trying to input the data in the class AAA to be applied in the UIView callSize and I need that to be appeared on the screen, bringing up the data I previously saved.

When I input info.myList.elements.x.value, it says myList has no member 'x'.

What should I do?

Comment: You want to access an object property that resides in a list. `info.myList[0].x`

Comment: in this call, `let callSize: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int))` every `Int` has to be replaced with a value